# How do I query a single field in AppEngine using JDO

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I've got a Product POJO that looks like.

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Product extends AbstractModel {
    @Persistent
    private String name;

    @Persistent
    private Key homePage;

    @Persistent
    private Boolean featured;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Key getHomePage() {
        return homePage;
    }

    public void setHomePage(Key homePage) {
        this.homePage = homePage;
    }

    public boolean isFeatured() {
        return featured;
    }

    public void setFeatured(Boolean featured) {
        this.featured = featured;
    }
}
```

My DataStore is currently completely empty.

I'd like to retrieve all homePage keys where featured is true for the Product.

I'm trying

```
PersistenceManager persistenceManager = getPersistenceManager();
Query query = persistenceManager.newQuery("SELECT homePage FROM " + getModelClass());
query.setFilter("featured == true");

List<Key> productPageKeys = (List<Key>) query.execute();
```

However this is giving me a null pointer error. How should I be constructing this query?

Cheers,
Peter

Comment: You're mixing single-string JDOQL and programmatic JDOQL. If specifying the string you do pm.newQuery("SELECT homePage FROM mydomain.MyModelClass WHERE featured == true");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do a projection, you would do something like

```
Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT myField FROM mydomain.MyClass WHERE featured == true");
List<String> results = (List<String>)q.execute();
```

where String is the type of my field. Any basic JDO documentation would define that. 
Internally GAE/J will retrieve the Entity, and then in the post-processing before returning it to the user it is manipulated into the projection you require.

As Nick pointed out in the other reply, this gives no performance gain over doing it yourself ... but then the whole point of a standard persistence API is to shield you from such datastore-specifics of having to do such extraction; it's all provided out of the box.

Comment: Yep, that does the trick. I thought this was doing some sort of mapping hibernate style to columns within the data store. Goes to show how well I'm being shielded. =) Even without a performance reason I prefer this method I think.

Comment: @DataNucleus, what if there are multiple string fields in MyClass and I want to retrieve only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Entities are stored as serialized blobs of data in the datastore, so it's not possible to retrieve and return a single field from an entity. You need to fetch the whole entity, and extract the field you care about yourself.

Comment: Nick, ProjectionResultTransformer has been present since 2009 to translate Entities into individual fields (hence supporting projection in JDOQL/JPQL). http://www.google.com/codesearch#79kbA0UmWLw/trunk/src/org/datanucleus/store/appengine/query/ProjectionResultTransformer.java

Comment: @DataNucleus I don't know if that's supported on App Engine or not, but the point remains that it will still result in fetching and decoding the entire entity from the datastore - so if the goal is performance improvements, there's no gain.