# Projection Queries in GAE/J with performance gain

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus, query-performance

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/projectionqueries) it says

> Projection queries allow you to query the Datastore ... at lower
>   latency and cost than retrieving the entire entity.

But [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020082/how-do-i-query-a-single-field-in-appengine-using-jdo) it says

> [Using JDO, I guess,] this gives no performance gain

So, do we have to use Datastore's low-level Java API to get the performance gain?

Comment: The second link says that using the low level API OR JDO doesn't give performance gain "it will still result in fetching and decoding the entire entity from the datastore - so if the goal is performance improvements, there's no gain".

Comment: But the first link is official. Projection queries allow lower cost & latency with low-level API.

Comment: sure and they also say JDO and JPA already have "projection queries" ... so their message is as clear as mud. Good luck on getting Google to clarify

Answer (score 1):

App Engine stores data in two ways: indexed properties are stored in indexes and then the entire entity is stored separately so it can be easily retrieved with a `get`. So if you need to access an unindexed property, there is no other option but to retrieve the entire entity.

If, however, all you need is a couple of indexed fields, a projection query will return those properties directly from the index data without fetching the entity itself, which obviously results in a significant performance gain as an extra step is completely eliminated and less data is returned.

Comment: So can I use JDO for the same performance? I mean how to detect if I gained performance or JDO gets whole entity and filters out unwanted members (i.e. fakes it)?